# Creating grid of hexagons

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, hexagonal-tiles

I have to do a "grid" like this:

[image: Harmonic table]
[Harmonic table](http://www.c-thru-music.com/cgi/?page=layout_octaves)

I'm trying to create a `ListView` with `ItemsSource="List<Note>"` where every odd note in the list is moved on the bottom...

Is the `ListView` the right control?

How can I draw an exact hexagon with faces that is near next object?

**EDIT:** hexagon drawing is solved... this is the xaml:

```
<Path d:LayoutOverrides="None" 
      d:LastTangent="0,0" Stroke="Blue" Fill="Red" 
      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
      Margin="0" Width="100" Height="100" x:Name="Path" 
  Stretch="Fill" 
      Data="M8.660254,0 L17.320508,5 17.320508,15 8.660254,20 0,15 0,5 8.660254,0 z"/>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The container for your notes would be an `ItemsControl` or a `ListBox` if you need to select items. Then you give your items a template using `ListBox.ItemTemplate` where you include your hexagon drawing. You have a nice tutorial on [Custom ListBox layout](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/CustomListBoxLayoutInWPF.aspx).

At this point, your hexagons are displayed one below the other as a ListBox does by default. To get your special layout, you have to change the `ListBox.ItemPanel`. Here you have two possibilities:

- either you use the `Canvas` panel that supports absolute positioning. In this case your items must have X and Y properties that you will use to position them.
- or you create a custom `Panel`, probably based on `Canvas`, that is able to convert your custom coordinate system (for example note name + octave number) into X and Y. A bit more difficult but much more reusable. An example of [Custom Panel on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37348/Creating-Custom-Panels-In-WPF.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

[HexGrid: CodeProject article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1195543/HexGrid)

[HexGrid: GitHub repository](https://github.com/AlexanderSharykin/HexGrid)

The key component of a possible solution is a WPF Panel which can arrange hexagonal elements (Standard Panels operate with rectangular child elements).  Take a look my HexGrid project (too large to post here). The cental part of it is a `HexGrid` (WPF `Panel` which arranges child elements in a honeycomb pattern). Child elements are represented by `HexItem`s (hexagon-shaped ContentControls). There is also `HexList` (selector ItemsControl which displays items in HexItem container on a HexGrid panel) which gives hex selection support out-of-box.

example of usage:

```
<hx:HexList Name="HexColors" Orientation="Vertical"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Padding="10"
            SelectedIndex="0"
            Background="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
            RowCount="5" ColumnCount="5">
    <hx:HexItem Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Background="#006699"/>
    <hx:HexItem Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Background="#0033CC"/>
    <hx:HexItem Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Background="#3333FF"/>
    <!--...-->
    <hx:HexItem Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Background="#CC9900"/>
    <hx:HexItem Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Background="#FF3300"/>
    <hx:HexItem Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3" Background="#CC0000"/>
</hx:HexList>
```

[image: hex color selector]

Comment: Have you published this on nuget?

Comment: @ΩmegaMan, no, I haven't. Doesn't seem to be much demand for it

Comment: That's ashame, looks like you put in a lot of work. I'd love to wire this into an app, but hesitant to copy/paste code. If you change your mind, do let us know.