# How can i create hexagon menu using WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, panel

Please I need to create hexagon menu in wpf as panel but I can't know how can I create panel as hexagon shape
note I need to create it not draw it.
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Maybe start with [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443598/creating-grid-of-hexagons), and see what you can do once you create the hexagonal controls?

Comment: Not this ,it's talk about drawing I need to create it as panel.

Comment: can you explain how you want controls in hexagon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like that:

```
<Window x:Class="HexagonMenu.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ButtonFocusVisual">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Border>
                            <Rectangle 
                                Margin="2"
                                StrokeThickness="1"
                                Stroke="#60000000"
                                StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="NormalBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="0.0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#CCC" Offset="1.0"/>
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="HorizontalNormalBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
            <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="0.0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#CCC" Offset="1.0"/>
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="LightBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="0.0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#EEE" Offset="1.0"/>
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="HorizontalLightBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
            <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="0.0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#EEE" Offset="1.0"/>
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="DarkBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="0.0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#AAA" Offset="1.0"/>
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="PressedBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Color="#BBB" Offset="0.0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#EEE" Offset="0.1"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#EEE" Offset="0.9"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="1.0"/>
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledForegroundBrush" Color="#888" />

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBackgroundBrush" Color="#EEE" />

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowBackgroundBrush" Color="#FFF" />

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectedBackgroundBrush" Color="#DDD" />

        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="50"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid>
                            <Path x:Name="Hexagon" Stroke="Black" Stretch="Fill" Fill="{StaticResource NormalBrush}" 
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                  Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"                                  
                                  Data="M8.660254,0 L17.320508,5 17.320508,15 8.660254,20 0,15 0,5 8.660254,0 z"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>                            
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="Hexagon" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource DarkBrush}" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="Hexagon" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource PressedBrush}" />                                
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter TargetName="Hexagon" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" />                                
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

    </Window.Resources>

    <DockPanel>
        <WrapPanel x:Name="MyHexagonMenu" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <Button Content="File" />
            <Button Content="Edit" />
            <Button Content="About" /> 
            <Button Content="Exit" />             
        </WrapPanel>

    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you just want a single polygonal `Path`, you can use:

```
<Path Width="64" Height="64" Stretch="Uniform" Fill="Blue"
      Data="M8.660254,0 L17.320508,5 17.320508,15 8.660254,20 0,15 0,5 8.660254,0 Z" />
```

On my machine that looks like this:

[image]

Adjust the `Width` and `Height` as needed. Note that the resulting shape is *not* square, but the `Stretch="Uniform"` will cause the shape to resize such that it fits within whatever dimensions you specify.

Comment: You could use a `RenderTransform` to rotate it.